# How often can x divided by 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a question, is there an operation, that can tell me instantly how often x can be divided by 2 (without a reminder).

I mean i can write an easy function:

```
function howOftenDividedByTwo(x)
{
    var c = 0;
    while(x%2==0)
    {
        c++;
        x/=2;
    }
    return c;
}

howOftenDividedByTwo(10) -> gives 1
howOftenDividedByTwo(20) -> gives 2
howOftenDividedByTwo(32) -> gives 5
```

And yes, there are some computer science hacks to get the answer, like shifting bits etc.

But i was looking for a mathematical way to describe this (to calculate this).

If this shouldn't be faster possible, can someone represent me this function as mathematical equation, that would be awesome too :)

Comment: Here is the divisibility rule for powers of 2, in case you don't already know it https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Divisibility_rules/Rule_for_2_and_powers_of_2_proof

Comment: The $2$-adic valuation is the exponent corresponding to the prime $2$ in the prime factorization. This exponent is the number of times we can divide by $2$ without remainder. If this exponent is large, probably there is no better general method than just dividing by $2$ until it is no more possible.

Comment: In C parlance (at least for typical machines), `x & (-x)` happens to be the largest power of $2$ dividing $x$ (so for `x=96` the answer would be $32$ instead of the desired $5=\log_232$)

Comment: See [Find the log base 2 of an N-bit integer in O(lg(N)) operations](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog).

Comment: If you want a mathematical equation, though slower than your code, you can get one from [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) and/or related [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula), noting that $n = {n \choose 1} = \frac{n!}{(n-1)!}$.